# Setting Preview layout

Tags: finder, pdf, preview

I usually use Preview to read my PDFs. Usually, the files are very long and I have to jump from, let's say, page 20 to page 200 continuously. Is there a way to set the Layout to two Columns or two Rows such that I can read page 20 in one side and page 200 to the other side within the same PDF file opened?

I am trying to do the same thing I do with Sublime Text ( View > Layout >  Columns:2 ) which is able to do so.

Answer (score 1):

will not take merit for someone else suggestions... here they give at least two good advices:

https://superuser.com/questions/794877/how-do-i-read-a-pdf-in-2-simultaneous-views-split-view-mac